# C# SQLite escape '=' sign in prepared statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, escaping, libsodium

I am currently developing my own password manager in c#.

I have a problem in my update function:

```
protected internal bool Update()
    {
        // the updatestring that gets insert into the sqlitecommand
        string updatestring = "";

        // the affected rows returned by ExecuteNonQuery()
        int affectedrows = 0;

        try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                int i = 1;

                // looping trough the dictionary that holds the data of the table
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> keyValuePair in ArrData)
                {
                    // format the update value e.g:  Id = @Id
                    updatestring += String.Format("{0} = @{1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Key);

                    // if its not the last value to be updated add a , to the string
                    if (i < ArrData.Count)
                    {
                        updatestring += ", ";
                    }

                    i++;
                }

                connection.Open();

                // building the commandtext TableName is set by the child class
                SQLiteCommand sqLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(String.Format("UPDATE {0} SET ({1})", TableName, updatestring), connection);
                sqLiteCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                // again looping trough the dictionary to add the parameters to the command
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> keyValuePair in ArrData)
                {
                    sqLiteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@" + keyValuePair.Key,  keyValuePair.Value));
                }

                affectedrows = sqLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            } 
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return affectedrows > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

I am using libsodium to encrypt the sensible data.
After encryption i encode the byte[] with base64.
The Problem here is that sqlite dont escape the '=' sign in my base64 encoded variables.

It throws an error saying that i have a sql logic error near '='

Do you guys have a smart solution for this kind of problem ?

Comment: When you have your `keyValuePair.Value` is a String and you have in your table the type varchar for that field, you don't have to surround it by quotation marks? Maybe thats why you are getting the error

Comment: What is the type of the field in your database? What I am trying to say is that it is not the same to do: `UPDATE TABLE1 SET Field = MyValue ` to do `UPDATE TABLE1 SET Field = 'MyValue' `, the second one is the correct to save strings in your table

Comment: i thought sqlite detect strings and add quotation marks by adding parameters to the command text. my data type of the field is TEXT. i think i have to check if the dynamic value is of type string and then adding quotation marks to it ?

Comment: In SQLServer you have to add the type of the parameter. As I am looking in SQLite this is not necesary. Can you try to add a value without special characters and see if it working?

Comment: It is working. First i tried it without encryption just simple words as "test". maybe i should just store it as binary so i dont have to deal with converting and checking from dynamic to string. that would just be one more line in the decrypt function to convert the binary back to base64...

Comment: Can you try to save text'= ? (take into account that there is a single quotation mark before the equal sign.

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: i will try it with bin2hex instead of base64 i guess that will solve the issue give me five minutes :D

Comment: I am testing and it seems that you don't have to scape the `=` when you execute the query without using parameters.

Comment: yes. its not the `=`  it is the `:` with it i seperating the encrypted message from the nonce... i will use another seperator for it to fix this issue. sorry for the misdirection

Comment: error fix: dont use () around the {1} value :D i updated my code above... such a simple mistake robs you of an hour.. omg :D but thank you for your help